# How do I group similar data points together and render it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to consolidate the data I get back into specific groups and render the group in the UI base on that data.

```html
"ServiceRequest": [
        {"Status": "Re-Open",
        },{
            "Status": "Open",
        },{
            "Status": "Customer?agent Action Needed",
        },{
            "Status": "Future Review",
        },{
            "Status": "Closed",
        },{
            "Status": "Request Declined",
        }{
            "Status": "Closed",
        },            
    }];
```

- Open indicator (prioritized as follows)

  - Re-Open
  - Open (includes New, Referred, In Progress)
- Pending indicator

  - Customer/Agent Action Needed
  - Future Review
- Closed indicator

  - Closed
  - Request Declined
  - Duplicate

Expected results

- Status: Open
- Status: Open
- Status: Pending
- Status: Pending
- Status: Closed
- Status: Closed
- Status: Closed

Using Angular to render

Answer (score 0):

You can try order by in ngrepeat

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items order by 'status'">Status:{{item.Status}}</li>
</ul>
```

Check this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters in here if you are not getting mapping from API. just introduce a function which return the status value.

```
$scope.getStatus = getStatus;
function getStatus (status){
//here you can declare your status mapping as you mentioned above
      var statuses = {
           "Re-Open" : "Open",
           "Closed" : "closed"
       }
       return statuses[status];
}

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="status in ServiceRequest">Status:{{getStatus(status)}}</li>
</ul>
```